# как анимировать scrollLeft не используя Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 bNext.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    bNext.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    banner_obj.scrollLeft += bannerSize; // это нужно анимировать
    setTimeout(function () { bNext.removeAttribute('disabled'); }, 333);
})
```

как нанести плавный переход на scrollLeft если н не является свойством CSS? 
И нужно это сделать не используя Jquery, т.к мне сказали что от этой библиотеки нужно отвыкать ибо она умирает по чуть-чуть.

Пробовал через библиотеку Move.js, но там нужно передавать в качестве аргумента название свойства (к примеру "width") а свойства "scrollLeft" не существует, как быть?

Comment: Значит `Move.js` проживет дольше чем `JQuery`?

Comment: Используйте [requestAnimationFrame](https://www.google.com/search?q=requestanimationframe).